# Configuration of Scala in IntelliJ (SBT)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I followed the getting started guide on Scala's website and once I switched from IDEA to SBT I started having problems. First, it didn't recognize the Scala framework and set the source folder, so I had to do that manually. (This is the easy part, just seems weird it doesn't do that by itself...)
Second, IntelliJ doesn't seem to recognize the code inside build.sbt. ('Cannot resolve symbol' everywhere). I'm not sure if it actually affects the compilation or not, but I would rather have it working as intended.
Third, it doesn't recognize the scalatest library, that I added following this guide - https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started-intellij-track/testing-scala-in-intellij-with-scalatest.html. (I first need to add the dependency to the build.sbt file but since it basically doesn't recognize the code there, this might be the problem).

So this is about it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and if it's just a stupid mistake on my part, I prefer not losing my head trying to figure it out by myself.
Also, if there's a more recommended way to work with Scala I'd love to hear it. The only reason I tried doing it in IntelliJ is because I recently worked in it and it seemed pretty nice.

Thanks!
(Also sorry if I messed up a bit, this is my first post)

Comment: No need to install SBT plugin separately. Scala plugin has SBT support bundled. Just try to open the project as SBT project by importing from existing sources: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sbt-support.html#import_sbt Provided that you are able to build the project by SBT from command line the importing process should complete successfully and configure all the libraries in IntelliJ IDEA project.

Comment: I tried importing and I get this error, hopefully it will tell you more than it tells me - https://i.gyazo.com/d4242921fe6657dcbdce5c3726233cc1.png

Answer (score 0):

First of all have you installed the sbt and Scala does it available for your cmd if yes then good otherwise do it first otherwise sbt will not be available for your terminal too.

Ok now once you have done that just go into project settings `ctrl+alt+s` go into plugin and  install sbt build tool plugin from the install plugin browse repository you will find sbt build tool install it. It will help you to recognise your build.sbt now setup Scala sdk for your project so go into the project settings `ctrl +shift+alt +s` and in top left click on + sign and choose jdk then select your Scala sdk from your location (most probably in program files Scala/bin dir).

Hope it will help you with your problem.

Comment: No need to install SBT plugin separately. Scala plugin has SBT support bundled.

Comment: I tried what you said and as Andrey said it didn't have any difference.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, IntelliJ Idea proposes to install Scala plugin when initially configured after installation. So, if you have IntelliJ Idea just for Scala and it still does not work anyway (no settings that are bad to lose and you have the Community version of Idea), then I would recommend reconfiguring it from scratch: close Idea, rename `.IdeaIC201x.y` in your home directory (in case you have **IntelliJ Idea Ultimate** this directory probably has slightly different name, and **I'm not sure you will not have problems with your license**, so it would probably better to skip this step) and restart Idea. Then on fifth page of the configuration wizard select Scala plugin installation. **Do not install separate SBT plugins.**

In case reconfiguring IntelliJ Idea is not an option for you, then you can try to fix existing installation: remove already installed plugins related to Scala or SBT and then install **just the Scala plugin using "Install JetBrains plugin" button**. It already has built-in and up-to-date SBT support.

Now your IntelliJ Idea should have very good support for Scala and SBT and it's time to create your Scala project. I usually just import a project checked out from VCS, but let's try to create a project from scratch. :) Go to `New project -> Scala -> sbt`. Now Idea will create you a `build.sbt` file, run `sbt` and try to import project settings from it. Unfortunately, `sbt` hangs at first initialization sometimes. For me it helps to just forcefully restart it (but wait enough time before and after), but I don't know the proper way. After import, you have your project directory structure set up, now you can start coding.